# SpringBoot + Soap Web-сервис - как работать с несколькими схемами

Tags: soap, java-8, веб-служба

При использовании подхода **CONTRACT FIRST**, мы используя ***.xsd** выполняем следующее:

- плагином **jaxb2-maven-plugin** генерируем классы, который будут соответствовать правилам работы с данными, описанными в схеме ***.xsd**
- создаем **endpoint**, класс который будет полученный запрос обрабатывать, а точнее получит из него нужные данные, который затем использует для составления запроса например в базу данных и из полученного ответа из базы данных, достает значения, перекладывает из в модель объекта класса (который ранее был сгенерирован автоматически на основе ***.xsd**) и затем данный объект помещает в **response** и отпрпавляет клиенту,
  приблизительно так

```java
@Endpoint
public class StudentDetailsEndpoint {

    private StudentRepository studentRepository;

    @Autowired
    public StudentDetailsEndpoint(StudentRepository studentRepository) {
        this.studentRepository = studentRepository;
    }

    @PayloadRoot(
            namespace = "http://in28minutes.com/students",
            localPart = "GetStudentDetailsRequest")
    @ResponsePayload
    public GetStudentDetailsResponse processCourseDetailsRequest(@RequestPayload GetStudentDetailsRequest request) {

        GetStudentDetailsResponse response = new GetStudentDetailsResponse();

        StudentDetails userDetails = getUserDetails(request);

        response.setStudentDetails(userDetails);

        return response;

    }
...
```

- затем создаем класс, который на основании ***xsd,** будет автоматически генерировать **контракт**, согласно которому клиенты должны общаться в веб-сервисом. Данный контракт называется - **WSDL**. В нем описано, по каким правилам клиентам, нужно строить вопросы для веб-сервиса.
  Кроме того, данный класс формирует **URL**, по которому данный веб-сервис доступен

Примерно так :

```java
@EnableWs
@Configuration
public class WebServiceConfig {

    @Bean

    public ServletRegistrationBean messageDispatcherServlet(ApplicationContext context) {

        MessageDispatcherServlet messageDispatcherServlet = new MessageDispatcherServlet();

        messageDispatcherServlet.setApplicationContext(context);

        messageDispatcherServlet.setTransformWsdlLocations(true);

        return new ServletRegistrationBean(messageDispatcherServlet, "/ws/*");

    }

    @Bean(name = "students")
    public DefaultWsdl11Definition defaultWsdl11Definition(XsdSchema studentsSchema) {

        DefaultWsdl11Definition definition = new DefaultWsdl11Definition();

        definition.setPortTypeName("StudentPort");

        definition.setTargetNamespace("http://in28minutes.com/students");

        definition.setLocationUri("/ws");

        definition.setSchema(studentsSchema);

        return definition;

    }

    @Bean

    public XsdSchema studentsSchema() {

        return new SimpleXsdSchema(new ClassPathResource("student-details.xsd"));

    }

}
```

Но это когда у вас одна модель данных (одна таблица в базе данных) и соответственно одна схема ***xsd**

А если у вас сложный запрос и он должен получать данные из нескольких связанных таблиц

Или же даже несколько запросов но отдельным разным бизнес-объектам (табшицам)

Как же создавать проект, **endpoints** и **WebServiceConfigS** в таком случае ?

Можете привести пример с пояснениями, как в этом случае происходит работа, как формируются **URL**, нужно ли придумывать разные названия для

```java
definition.setPortTypeName("StudentPort");
```

и т.д ?

Answer (score 1):

Можно сколько угодно создавать веб-сервисов в одном приложении, на каждый веб-сервис одна **xsd**.

- Создать  для каждой xsd свой **WebServiceConfig** *******,

который будет публиковать уникальный документ WSDL

- Для каждого настроенного веб-сервиса, нужно создать свой **Endpoint**
- WebServicConfig... должен получить свою уникальную схему

```java
@Bean(name = "movies")
    public DefaultWsdl11Definition defaultWsdl11Definition(@Qualifier("moviesSchema") XsdSchema schema){
```

```java
@Bean(name = "moviesSchema")
    public XsdSchema moviesSchema(){

        return new SimpleXsdSchema(new ClassPathResource("/xsd/movie/movies.xsd"));

    }
```

более развернуто можно увидеть здесь:

https://www.javaspringclub.com/publish-and-consume-soap-web-services-using-spring-boot-part-1/